# Twilio configuration Profile SID

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using the Twilio Video API. In my node.js I used this code,

```
var grant = new VideoGrant();
```

It requires `configurationProfileSid` but I can't find docs on how to get it?
I think it is a capability token.
But how can I get it using twilio node js?
Or is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Configuration Profiles used to be required, but have been deprecated. So you no longer need the `configurationProfileSid`. You can give access to particular rooms though.

Here's an [example Node.js application that generates access tokens for a Video application](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/video-access-token-server-node). The important part is the route that generates the token:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
    // containing the grant we just created
    var token = new AccessToken(
        process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
        process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
        process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
    );

    // Assign identity to the token
    token.identity = request.query.identity || 'identity';

    // Grant the access token Twilio Video capabilities
    var grant = new VideoGrant();
    grant.room = request.query.room;
    token.addGrant(grant);

    // Serialize the token to a JWT string
    response.send(token.toJwt());
});
```

This [documentation on access tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/user-identity-access-tokens) should help too.